# About where-object cmdlet

Tags: powershell

I'm just starting with PowerShell, I have a question about this command:

```
Get-WindowsFeature | where installed
```

It returns me the features installed, now I would like to have all the features removed or available, but when I replace "installed" with removed/available, it shows me nothing, why?

Thanks guys!

Comment: The correct syntax is `Get-WindowsFeature | where installed` See [Get-WindowsFeature](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/jj205469(v=wps.630).aspx) At the bottom of the link is an example for what you ask. `Get-WindowsFeature –ComputerName Server01 | Where InstallState -Eq Removed`

Comment: For future questions, it helps to show the exactly command line you tried, and what the result was.

Comment: Alright, but my last sentence respond to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the `Installed` you checked was a Boolean property.  It's true or false, and you were checking for all objects where it was `$True`.
`Removed` and `Available` are possible values of `InstallState`, not properties directly.

You can see this with

```
PS> Get-Windowsfeature | Get-Member
   TypeName: Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.Feature 
Name                      MemberType Definition
----                      ---------- ----------
<extra removed>
Installed                 Property   bool Installed {get;}
InstallState              Property   Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.InstallState InstallState {get;}
<extra removed>
```

Try one of these:

```
Get-Windowsfeature | Where-Object { -not $_.Installed }
Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object { $_.InstallState -eq "Available" }
Get-WindowsFeature | Where-Object { $_.InstallState -eq "Removed" }
```